# htaccess for www force on Domain + Subdomain and only SSL for Subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have a website and i got some real problem with .htaccess... 
I tried for 6 hours to solve it.. i hope someone can help me. I just added a subdomain incl. ssl...

Problem: 
1.) For the Main Domain (www.domain.com) in need the following

- example.com should be transformed to www.example.com
- rewrite www.example.com/index.html to www.example.com
- no SSL --> http

The html pages for the main domain are located in the root folder

2.) For my Subdomain xy.domain.com i need:

- also xy.domain.com --> www.xy.domain.com
- Force SSL and https

The content for the subdomain is located in root/folder2... subdomain redirects to /folder2

I hope someone has a solution :)
Thanks a lot!

**Recent htaccess looks like this**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have in your config?

Comment: @xlm sure i just added it in my questions - sorry! I already tryed a lot of different solutions by searching for similar topics but i couldnt find the right solution - i'm far from being good at programming :)

Answer (score 0):

So after some work i came to this point ... it works but not perfect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(sub\.domain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

If someone could tell me please how i can implement a rule that includes the following rewrite:
`http://www.domain.com/folder1` to `https://www.sub.domain.com`

What i coouldnt figure out how to force the www. to the sub...